# What has increased every year for 25 years for the companies on the S&P 500 Dividend Aristocrats list?

Tags: dividends

Question regarding 25 consecutive years of **increased dividend payouts** for the S&P 500 Dividend Aristocrats.

What exactly is "increasing"?

Is it:

(A) Dividend **payouts as a percentage of stock price** on date of payout (dividend yield).

or

(B) **Payout per share**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What has been increasing is the payout per share. The company determines the payout per share. The market determines the percentage yield by varying the stock price.

Comment: Would it be a split-adjusted payout per share? Just wondering how that would look or not since a stock split would dramatically increase the dividend in this case otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the S&P analysis is split adjusted. Some web sites may not be.